# how to uninstall/remove abaqus from Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

What should I do to uninstall/remove Abaqus from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

I did not install abaqus by commmand "sudo apt-get ....", now I don't know how to remove it from ubuntu. I followed instruction as shown in the following [link](https://sites.google.com/site/abaqus2010/help_0). Could anyone help me to solve?

Comment: how you installed it via apt-get ?

Comment: Because I did not install abaqus by commmand "sudo apt-get ....", now I don't know how to remove it from ubuntu.

I followed instruction as shown in the following link

https://sites.google.com/site/abaqus2010/help_0

Could anyone help me to solve?

Thanks